# change router default gateway name

Tags: wireless-networking

Currently to access my router settings I could either go to http://my.content or http://192.168.88.1 so what I would like to do is change my.content for something else, the router is running on ubuntu.

Comment: What other desired name? The "friendly" name works because the router routes that line to itself. You can set a custom friendly name in your etc hosts file as described below, but this will only work on the computer it is set on.

Answer (score 0):

Add something like

```
 192.168.88.1    your.desired.name
```

to `/etc/hosts`